# Using zlib to compress a NumPy array in Cython

Tags: python, c, numpy, cython, zlib

I'm working on a system to cache the intermediate products of some matrix algebra problems I'm trying to accelerate by using the `zlib` package in Python to write NumPy arrays to a database for later retrieval. I'd like to take advantage of Cython for the speed improvement and the ability to multithread by releasing the GIL.

The code I have almost functions, but for a couple of problems that I'm finding quite vexing. First, despite the `compress2` function I import from the C library returning with status code 0 (i.e., compression succeeded), my output is always truncated, irrespective of how big an output buffer I setup. Second, when I do what I want to and try to compress a NumPy array, the compression function only returns the first byte or two.

```
#include <zlib.h>
cimport numpy as np
from libc.stdio cimport printf
from libc.stdlib cimport malloc, free

cdef extern from "zlib.h":
    ctypedef unsigned char Bytef
    ctypedef unsigned long uLongf
    ctypedef long unsigned uLong

    int compress2 (Bytef *, uLongf *, Bytef *, uLong, int)


def __cache_write(np.ndarray weights):
    weight_string = weights.tostring()
    cdef char* c_weight_string = weight_string
    cdef char compressed[1000]
    cdef uLongf destlen = sizeof(compressed)
    cdef int status = compress2(<Bytef *>compressed, &destlen, <Bytef *>c_weight_string, sizeof(c_weight_string), 6)
    cdef bytes result = compressed

    return status, result
```

I do have some vague idea that part of the reason I'm getting truncated output has to do with the `.tostring()` function returning a string of bytes rather than a string in ASCII or whatever. But I also get truncated output when I have the function accept a Python string instead (e.g., `'abc'`).

```
In [5]: __cache_write(np.ones(10))
Out[5]: (0, 'x\x9cKLJf')
...
In [7]: zlib.compress(np.ones(10).tostring())
Out[7]: 'x\x9cc`\x00\x81\x0f\xf6\x0cT\xa2\x01\xbf\xad\x0b\xd7'
```

This is not my area of expertise, so I apologize for any neophyte mistakes!

**Update 1:**

As the first answerer pointed out, I messed up the call to the `compress2` function. Swapping out `sizeof(c_weight_string)` for `len(weight_string)` does produce something that looks better, though it hasn't resolved all the problems.

When I switch the input argument to be a string and try it with something like `'abc'`, I get `"x\x9cKLJ\x06\x00\x02M\x01'"` calling the Python `zlib` package, but `'x\x9cKLJf\xc0\t\xe4\xfb7\xb6\xd430<\x10\x87\xd06h\xd2\x8cP\xfa\x83\x1cD^\x01\xa4\x0e'` from my function. (This might have something to do with what exactly is being compressed, but I also get a missing termination character error when I try to decompress it, which suggests something else is going on.) And when I try to compress a NumPy vector, I wind up with just the first few bytes:

```
'x\x9cc`'
```

instead of:

```
'x\x9cc`\x00\x81\x0f\xf6\x0cT\xa2\x01\xbf\xad\x0b\xd7'.
```

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof(c_weight_string)` is the size of a `char*`, not the size of the string. Replace that with `len(weight_string)` to get the correct size. I believe `sizeof(destlen)` is ok though since this is a static array.

The second issue is that the output string contains atleast one null character, and the conversion to a bytearray treats those as the end of the output stream. To solve this you can do

```
# at top of file
from cpython cimport PyBytes_FromStringAndSize

# then in your function
cdef int status = compress2(<Bytef *>compressed, &destlen, <Bytef *>c_weight_string, len(weight_string), 6)
# generate result while passing the length too
cdef bytes result = PyBytes_FromStringAndSize(compressed,destlen)
```

This is a Python3 solution. The function you have to call is likely slightly different for Python 2.

---

You might also consider `numpy.savez_compressed` which saves to a compressed binary format, or using the [Python zlib module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zlib.html) directly (Cython is unlikely to get you much speed here, since the effort is all in the zlib code anyway, and does require you to understand c)

Comment: OK, thanks. The fourth argument to the compress function was definitely at least part of the problem. I'm still seeing some issues with my function, though. (I'll update the question with more notes, as that seems clearer.)

Re the other note, this is only part of the function, and I'd like to be able to unlock the GIL. I think I anticipated the C compression part would be easier than it's been.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I suspect the Python zlib module and `numpy.savez_compressed` release the GIL themselves. I'm not sure about the remaining issues.